# How to query "findCurrentPlace" in Google's new Places SDK client? I want to add custom radius and type for search nearby places

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm using Google's new Places SDK client. I want to show places for x radius and type = CAFE, BANK etc. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
val placesClient = Places.createClient(this)

        val placeFields = arrayListOf(
            Place.Field.NAME,
            Place.Field.LAT_LNG
        )
        val request = FindCurrentPlaceRequest.builder(placeFields).build()
        placesClient.findCurrentPlace(request).addOnSuccessListener { placeResponse ->
            placeResponse.placeLikelihoods.forEach {
                Log.i("Places", String.format("Place '%s' has likelihood: %s",
                    it.place.latLng.toString(),
                    it.place.name
                ))
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you find the answer? I am also looking for the same

Comment: Hi Akash, The SDK mentioned above is only responsible to find the likelihood i.e. your location is similar to which of the nearby places. I suggest you, use the Places API instead of Places SDK. Do let me know if you find another alternative. Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: I have used Google Maps API to get nearby places with filters like radius, type etc. Thanks for showing interest